# Linking pickers in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, picker

I have a question regarding pickers in swift. Just began programming in IOS and i had no prior experience in Objective-C. We have to calculate (Total Cost of Ownership) for a project and at the moment i am trying to get the information in pickers.

Problem is : I have made multiple arrays and *var segment* is in the first picker. But if you choose the first index "A" it should show array carA, and if i choose segment "B" it should show the carB Array.

This is my code until now!. i hope someone can help me :).

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate {
    var segment = ["A","B","C","D","E"]
    var kilometers = ["24000","36000","48000"]
    var looptijd = ["2 jaar","3 jaar","5 jaar"]
    var carA = ["Toyota Aygo","Suzuki Swift"]
    var carB = ["Prius","Peugeot 207"]
    var carC = ["Lexus ch270","audi a3"]
    var carD = ["Lexus..","BMW X6"]
    @IBOutlet weak var segmentLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var kilometersLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var looptijdLabel: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        segmentLabel.text = segment[0]
        kilometersLabel.text = kilometers[0]
        looptijdLabel.text = looptijd[0]
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 4
    }
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        if (component == 0 ) {
            return segment.count
        } else {
            if(component == 1) {
                return kilometers.count
            }
            if(component == 2) {
                return looptijd.count
            }
            if(component == 3) {
                return carA.count
            }
        }
        return component
    }
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
        if (component == 0 ) {
            return segment[row]
        } else  {
            if(component == 1) {
                return kilometers[row]
            }
            if(component == 2) {
                return looptijd[row]
            }
            if(component == 3){
                return carA[row]
            }
            return nil     // ARE YOU SURE RETURN IT IS NO AFTER CURLY BRACKETS ?
        }                  // THATS WHY YOU SHOULD BETTER INDENT YOUR CODE
    }
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        if(component == 0){
            var segmentSelected = segment[row]
            segmentLabel.text = segmentSelected
        } else {
            if(component == 1) {
                var kilometersSelected = kilometers[row]
                kilometersLabel.text = kilometersSelected
            }
            if(component == 2){
                var looptijdSelected = looptijd[row]
                looptijdLabel.text = looptijdSelected
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the calculation you need to do there?

Comment: What if you had a UISegmentedControl outside the UIPickerView and when you select A,B,C,D there, it reloads the pickerView with the correct array?

Comment: I suggest you taking a look at `switch` statement.

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus i need to calculate Total Cost of Ownership for people leasing cars. the calculation is based on (New Cost - Cost after term) + Realistic Gas usage(over the selected term) + Taxes(based on weight and type of fuel).

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus i am getting an error while executing your code.

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value and i get this at this line. picker.delegate = self

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you need to create one more string array. This array can hold the selection and then reload components as first component selected is changed.

First it should be `CarA`. So the default selection for that array will be first array, and then change this array value when component 0 row value is changed.

You need to reassign selection array value in `pickerView(_:didSelectRow:InComponent:)` method and then after reload all picker components will do the trick.

Below code will work for you I have tested it, reimplement your logic and still if it not works leave a comment I will provide demo for you.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

     @IBOutlet weak var picker: UIPickerView!   

     var segment:    [String]!
     var kilometers: [String]!
     var looptijd:   [String]!
     var carA:       [String]!
     var carB:       [String]!
     var carC:       [String]!
     var carD:       [String]!

     var selectionArray:       [String]!

     @IBOutlet weak var segmentLabel: UILabel!
     @IBOutlet weak var kilometersLabel: UILabel!
     @IBOutlet weak var looptijdLabel: UILabel!

     override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         segment = ["A","B","C","D","E"]
         kilometers = ["24000","36000","48000"]
         looptijd = ["2 jaar","3 jaar","5 jaar"]
         carA = ["Toyota Aygo","Suzuki Swift"]
         carB = ["Prius","Peugeot 207"]
         carC = ["Lexus ch270","audi a3"]
         carD = ["Lexus..","BMW X6"]

         selectionArray = carA
         segmentLabel.text = segment[0]
         kilometersLabel.text = kilometers[0]
         looptijdLabel.text = looptijd[0]

         picker.delegate = self
         picker.dataSource = self

     }

     override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
         super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
         // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
     }


     func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
         return 4
     }

     func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
         if (component == 0 ) {
             return segment.count
         } else {
             if(component == 1) {
                 return kilometers.count
             }
             if(component == 2) {
                 return looptijd.count
             }
             if(component == 3) {
                 return carA.count
             }
         }
         return component
     }

     func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
         if (component == 0) {
             return segment[row]
         } else  {
             if(component == 1) {
                 return kilometers[row]
             }
             if(component == 2) {
                 return looptijd[row]
             }
             if(component == 3){
                 return selectionArray[row]
             }
             return nil     // ARE YOU SURE RETURN IT IS NO AFTER CURLY BRACKETS ?
         }                  // THATS WHY YOU SHOULD BETTER INDENT YOUR CODE
     }

     func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
         if (component == 0) {
             var selectedString = segment[row];
             segmentLabel.text = selectedString

             if (selectedString == segment[0]) {
                 selectionArray = carA
             } else if (selectedString == segment[1]) {
                 selectionArray = carB
             } else if (selectedString == segment[2]) {
                 selectionArray = carC
             } else if (selectedString == segment[3]) {
                 selectionArray = carD
             }
             picker.reloadAllComponents()
         } else {
             if(component == 1) {
                 var kilometersSelected = kilometers[row]
                 kilometersLabel.text = kilometersSelected
             }
             if(component == 2){
                 var looptijdSelected = looptijd[row]
                 looptijdLabel.text = looptijdSelected
             }
         }
    }

    deinit {
        self.picker.delegate = nil
        self.picker.dataSource = nil
    }
}
```